# Laravel использовать метод в разных контроллерах

Tags: laravel

У меня есть метод который я использую в разных контроллерах, на примере лога данных , как я могу вынести метод куда нибудь отдельно и его просто использовать ? Что мне для этого нужно сделать в Laravel ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение из англоязычного стака:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021662/how-to-create-global-function-that-can-be-accessed-from-any-controller-and-blade

От себя добавлю, что все методы в созданном классе желательно делать статичными, например:

```
namespace App\Helper;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Helper
{
    private static authorized()
    {
        return Auth::check();
    }
}
```

если метод статичен, вам не придётся создавать объект класса, достаточно будет в контроллере вызвать:

```
Helper::auth();
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть `App/Http/Controllers/Controller.php`, который по-умолчанию наследуют все остальные контроллеры, например, `ExampleController`, созданный для примера

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    //
}
```

Просто напишите там свой метод, он станет доступен автоматически всем наследникам.

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать файл `helpers.php` и разместить его (как пример) в каталоге `app`

Добавить данный файл в автозагрузку внеся изменения в файл `composer.json` в секцию `autoload`. Затем выполнить `composer update`

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
```

Теперь при необходимости вы можете добавлять любые функции в созданный файл и они будут доступны из любого места приложения. Например:

```
    <?php // helpers.php

    function calc($a, $b)
    {
        return $a+$b;
    }
```

и далее в проекте использовать просто вызов `calc(2,3)`

Можно использовать как в шаблонах blade так и в контроллерах и всех созданных классах.

Также в данном файле вы сможете использовать все фасады и встроенные функции laravel.